# Puppeteer fails in docker container: "browser has disconnected!"

Tags: docker, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I wrote a script that uses Puppeteer v1.12.2 to grab some info from a webpage. It runs on my local machine (Ubuntu 18.04) with node v10.15.1, and it runs on my machine in a docker container with `node:10-slim`.

I pushed the image to a Google Cloud container registry, and pulled it on a Google Compute Engine machine (Ubuntu 18.04) and there it fails when Puppeteer loads the page:

```
Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
at CDPSession.LifecycleWatcher._eventListeners.helper.addEventListener (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:47:107)
at CDPSession.emit (events.js:182:13)
at CDPSession._onClosed (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
at Connection._onClose (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:138:15)
at WebSocketTransport._ws.addEventListener.event (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:45:22)
at WebSocket.onClose (/www/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at WebSocket.emitClose (/www/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:180:10)
at Socket.socketOnClose (/www/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:805:15)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
  -- ASYNC --
at Frame.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:108:27)
at Page.goto (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:662:49)
at Page.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:109:23)
at scrapeLicence (/www/scrapeLicenceById.js:30:33)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I've seen other discussions of this error "Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!" fix it by adding `await`s, but I'm already `await`ing every method I call on the browser/page objects, so I'm running the whole script procedurally with no callbacks. It runs as expected on my local computer, but not on the GCE instance. Why would it behave differently on a different machine? and what causes the browser to "disconnect"?

---

Update: Here's a minimal reproduction of the script that's having the error:

**scrape.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const verbose = true;

async function run() {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--window-size=1920x1080',
            ],
        });

        const pageUrl = 'https://google.com';

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        page.once('load', () => {
            if (verbose) console.log(`Page loaded.`);
        });

        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });

        const response = await page.goto(pageUrl, {
            timeout: 25000,
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        });
        if (response._status >= 400) {
            console.error('Error from server:', response);
            throw new Error('Error response from server');
        }

        console.log('page ok?');

        await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

run();
```

And here's the **Dockerfile** I'm using to build the image:

```
FROM node:10-slim

# -------- install chrome ----------
# See https://crbug.com/795759
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main">> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb

ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

# ------------------

# Set work directory to /www
WORKDIR /www

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json package.json
RUN yarn install

# Copy script files
COPY . .

# Runs "/usr/bin/dumb-init -- node scrape.js"
ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "scrape.js"]
```

Comment: What is the configuration for the GCE? Maybe the ram and storage is different, maybe the permission is different somewhere?

Comment: Also, can you share a bit of your code?

Comment: Sure, I updated my question with a sample of the script, and the Dockerfile I'm using. I was trying to run the script on a sever, do you think memory could be a problem? (And would it have this result, where the browser just disconnects with no notice?)

Comment: I got it working by adding this line to the `puppeteer.launch` options:

    `executablePath: 'google-chrome',`

But I'm still very confused about how it would have worked on my computer, if it wasn't working on all of the other environments when I tried it...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I'm still confused about what was going on, and why that line appears to fix it!

Comment: Google keyboard did not write "Docker" properly. Apologies. Okay, so you are installing google-chrome, so you have to use that one when you are running your script. I will clarify this whole thing in an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same problem that affects [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54837726/6161265).

Basically puppeteer 1.12.2 installs a development version 73 of chromium , which has some small bugs that stops it from loading certain website/script and/or stop it from running on specific platform.

The solution is either use an previous puppeteer version 1.11.0, or use a different stable chrome version.

Which is why `executablePath: 'google-chrome'` made the difference. It was using a stable version rather than the provided version.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Any idea why the container was working on my local computer but nowhere else?

Comment: I faced the problem on my local and server both before writing the answer. This might be due to the version problem i mentioned. If you comply remove now_modules folder and try it with the version as specified above, you might see a difference on server and computer. However if the answer is enough, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: This solved it for me too.  Downgraded to Puppeteer 1.11.0, my `page.click` problem in CircleCI went away.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: This answer definitely fixes the problem I was having, but I was also asking why it worked on my local docker and not anywhere else. It's my fault for asking two different questions in one post. I'll accept this as the answer, but I welcome any extra feedback about the other question too! I wonder if it has do do with docker caching a layer somewhere? I didn't mention in the question, but the dockerfile also copies the yarn.lock file so the node_modules should be the same too.

Comment: I was asking that exact thing. Maybe it's causing because of caching which you can verify by deleting the node_modules and yarn.lock

Comment: In my case, even having the npm install done in the running docker container didn't fix the issue, so I don't think it's a `node_modules` or docker layer caching issue.

Comment: Can you install puppeteer from tip of tree/GitHub instead of npm and see if issue persists?